# Write binary data to stdout in Crystal

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm trying to output binary data to stdout (to serve some dynamic binary data using Kemal).

Here is a test:

```
size = File.size( "./img.png" )
slice = Slice( UInt8 ).new( size )
File.open( "./img.png" ) do |file|
  file.read_fully( slice )
end
```

I tried without success:

```
slice
slice.hexdump
slice.hexstring
slice.to_a
slice.to_s
slice.to_unsafe.value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use [`IO#write(Slice)`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.20.1/IO.html#write%28slice%3ASlice%28UInt8%29%29%3ANil-instance-method):

```
STDOUT.write(slice)
```

Comment: Works for STDOUT. But I discovered that Kemal doesn't work as I expected, I need to return the dinary data directly I suppose

Comment: Just as a side note, this can be useful: `io = IO::Memory.new` `io.write( slice )` `io.to_s`